# recompiled ruby - now "mach-o, but wrong architecture" macvim error

Tags: ruby, vim, macvim

I am recieving the following error when trying to use MacVim:

```
~$mvim index.php 
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/lib/libruby.1.dylib
  Referenced from: /Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/MacOS/Vim
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /usr/lib/libruby.1.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture
    /usr/lib/libruby.1.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture
Trace/BPT trap
```

Also of interest:

```
~$/usr/lib/libruby.(tab)
libruby.1.dylib  libruby.dylib
```

I recompiled ruby as stated here: [hivelogic ruby setup](http://hivelogic.com/articles/compiling-ruby-rubygems-and-rails-on-snow-leopard/). I use macvim heavily, and use gem based plugins  such as [fuzzyfinder_textmate](http://github.com/jamis/fuzzyfinder_textmate).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating to the latest snapshot fixed this. [Snapshot link](http://code.google.com/p/macvim/wiki/Snapshot)